# Getting image from mp4 video using ffmpeg in YII

Tags: php, yii, ffmpeg

I have written a code to get an image from an uploaded mp4 video using ffmpeg in YII.

In localhost, when i have written absolute path like `d:/wamp/www/projectname/ffmpeg` like this, it is working perfectly and i am getting image but when I tried like below using `baseurl`

```
$var="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
$ffmpeg = $var."/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe";
```

I am unable to get the image from video.

Here is my code

```
$var="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
$ffmpeg = $var."/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe";
// $uploaddir is my file upload path
$video = $uploaddir.$image_name;  
//where to save the image
$iname = basename($image_name, ".mp4");
$image = $uploaddir.'/'.$iname.'_img.jpg';  
//time to take screenshot at  
$interval = 5;  
//screenshot size  pn 
$size = '640x480';  
//ffmpeg command  
$cmd="$ffmpeg -i ".$video." -ss 00:00:01.100 -f image2 -vframes 1 ".$image;
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to execute "http://foo.bar/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe",
exec requires a absolute path to the binary:

```
/**
 * return d:/wamp/www/projectname
 */
$var = dirname(Yii::app()->getBasePath());
$ffmpeg = $var."/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe";
if(!file_exists($ffmpeg))
   exit("sorry dude, i cant find ffmpeg.exe!");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried your code, it is working fine in my local host, but coming to server, it is not working.

Comment: i have modified my code. When the error is fired on your server, the ffmpeg.exe is not located at d:/wamp/www/projectname/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe. In this case you have to install ffmpeg on server or provide a API on your local environment.

Comment: hi henry, thanks for your reply... i have changed the code as per your lines but i am not getting any image from the video, in local it is working perfectly, and when we have written file exists also it's not showing any error and file exists in the folder with the given path but image not getting from the video