# Highlight an array of dates in PickMeUp plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, highlight

I am using the [PickMeUp](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp) JS calendar plugin in my project.

The problem I'm having is that I want to be able to let the user select multiple dates while, simultaneously, displaying pre-selected dates from my server-side database. However, I am not able to get this to work: PickMeUp doesn't  seem to have such an option.

Does anybody know how I can highlight a given set of dates in the datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most definitely possible.

What you need to do is load the dates from the database into an array. You can then check this array with `PickMeUp`'s [`object render event`](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#object-render-date) and check every date against the dates from the array. If any of the dates coincide, you return the event `class_name` with a new css class. You can then use this css class to highlight the dates from the database.

For example, the following **Javascript/jQuery** illustrates what I mean:

```
// Creating some 'sample' dates (you just load this from the database instead)
var datesFromDatabase = [];
var d = new Date();
for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    var tempDay = new Date(); tempDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tempDay.setDate(d.getDate()-i);
    datesFromDatabase.push(tempDay.getTime());
}

$(function () {
    $('.multiple').pickmeup({
        flat: true,
        mode: 'multiple',
        // Before rendering dates, highlight if from database
        render: function(date) {
            if ($.inArray(date.getTime(), datesFromDatabase) > -1){
                return {
                    class_name : 'highlight'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
// Little hack to deselect current day: PickMeUp forces you to have a default date :(
$('.pmu-today').click();
```

With the following **CSS**:

```
.highlight:not(.pmu-today) {
    background: #8FC490;
}
.highlight:not(.pmu-today):hover {
    background: #136a9f !important;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b3L2bo5n/)

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul, I have another issue, hope you will clear my issue. Please check the below URL  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243383/getting-image-from-mp4-video-using-ffmpeg-in-yii

Comment: hi, is there any way to remove the default date selection in pickmeup js?

Comment: @ramakoti Yes. Please re-read my answer: I already included the little trick to deselect the current day. However, by default the current day is *highlighted*. The little trick just *deselects* it.

Comment: @ramakoti If you also don't want to *highlight* the current day, then you can do so by changing the `.pmu-today` colors. See [**this jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L274ph6a/).